# Why does Xorg crash all of a sudden in Ubuntu 15.10 and does a forced log-out?

Tags: 15.10

I was just wondering if there are any known issues with Ubuntu 15.10.....my OS just logs out randomly, closing down all windows. This has been happening since I upgraded.

Has anyone been experiencing the same issue? Is there a way to check in a log why this has been happening?

It has just happened again and I took a screenshot of the window that popped up (after login):
[image]

UPDATE: (for Dain)
Here is what "dmesg" gives me....have a look please:
[image]

Comment: I have a similar problem, X crashes and go back to login. This happens, though, only when using Spotify. Since it is a proprietary application and it's not clear to me to whom should I report the bug, I solved my problem by using it from web browser.

Comment: I assume this will get closed as too generic/vague. Answered cuz it was a bit too long for a comment. To anyone: feel free to delete it if this is closed  ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind then it gets closed. :)

Comment: For bugs it's always better to search Launchpad. If you want to ask about your specific issue, edit the question. Otherwise, voting to close

Comment: Random "X bugs" are usually caused by GPU errors. Are there any errors in the `dmesg` output?

Comment: @bain Have a look at the OP. Just updated it with a screenshot that I got when typed dmesg in terminal.

Comment: Images are not ideal. Could you copy the dmesg text and paste it to [http://paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and then put the link here. The error fragment in the image does appear to be a Nouveau bug, it appears in one of the error logs attached to [freedesktop bug #89558](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89558), so that could be relevant.

Comment: btw you could try [16.04 daily](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) - it has a more recent kernel where the bug may be fixed.

Comment: @bain Thanks for getting back. I'll post it as soon as it happens again. Then I copy it and put it into paste.ubuntu. Is there a way to locate the log that contains this error message from yesterday? I really dont want to upgrade just yet. With new distros there are issues....all the time. Cheers.

Comment: @dadexix86 I'd definitely report the problem. Also I'd open a question here using bain's instrustions......meaning I'd copy the entire log of what has really happened. Good luck solving it.

Comment: `/var/log/kern.log` `/var/log/kern.log.*` `/var/log/syslog` etc.

Comment: btw an install of 16.04 isn't a terrible idea - it's a LTS release which will be supported for 5 years whereas 15.10 support will end in 6 months time.

Comment: @bain I'll surely install it...the moment it is officially out.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are know issues with 15.10. We have them collected [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily). Current tally:

- [1793 New bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+bugs?search=Search&field.status=New)
- [1966 Open bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+bugs)
- [22 In-progress bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+bugs?search=Search&field.status=In%20Progress)
- [4 Critical bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+bugs?search=Search&field.importance=Critical&field.status=New&field.status=Incomplete&field.status=Confirmed&field.status=Triaged&field.status=In+Progress&field.status=Fix+Committed) (these have all been triaged and 1 has a fix released)
- [149 High importance bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+bugs?search=Search&field.importance=Critical&field.status=New&field.status=Incomplete&field.status=Confirmed&field.status=Triaged&field.status=In+Progress&field.status=Fix+Committed)
- [1 Incomplete bug (can expire)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+expirable-bugs)

It might be worth it to check the critical and high importance bugs for something similar to your case.

---

> my OS just logs out randomly, closing down all windows. This has been happening since I upgraded.

That is a bit vague to go on. Try to narrow it down to something more specific.

In general you need to check log files in /var/log and find lines that have "critical" in it. Check `~/.xsession.errors` and `dmesg` for error references (`grep ERROR {file}` is a useful method). Truly random crashes should be hardware related, otherwise the crash should be "local" (as in related to a process). Besides log files you should also do a memory check and have a look at your disks health (-> disk utility).

Often also a good idea is to uninstall 3rd party apps and drivers one at a time and see if those crashes disappear.

Comment: There is nothing else to say....it logs out to the login screen. I mean I cant give you more information. That's what's happening. I am using it and all of a sudden it logs out as if I hit the "log out" button.

Comment: There will always be something to why this is happening. Either in /var/log/ or in something like ~/.xsession.errors (but where... depends on why it happens ;-) )